# Morphia throwing inner exception when saving basic entity

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have been trying to save a POJO with Morphia without luck. I´ve got the following code, which is simple:

```
final Morphia morphia = new Morphia();

morphia.mapPackage("entities.users");

final Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient(), "test_table");
datastore.ensureIndexes();
datastore.save(user);
```

However, **the weird thing is that `datastore.ensureIndexes()` is throwing a weird, internal exception which depends on Morphia:**

```
WARNING: Parameterized types are treated as untyped Objects. See field 'assertionLock' on class java.lang.ClassLoader
org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Cannot use non-static inner class: class java.security.ProtectionDomain$Key. Please make static.
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappedClass.basicValidate(MappedClass.java:495)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappedClass.<init>(MappedClass.java:123)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.getMappedClass(Mapper.java:451)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.processEmbeddedAnnotations(DatastoreImpl.java:1545)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:1185)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.processEmbeddedAnnotations(DatastoreImpl.java:1545)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:1185)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.processEmbeddedAnnotations(DatastoreImpl.java:1545)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:1185)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.processEmbeddedAnnotations(DatastoreImpl.java:1545)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:1185)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.processEmbeddedAnnotations(DatastoreImpl.java:1545)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:1185)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.processEmbeddedAnnotations(DatastoreImpl.java:1545)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:1185)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.processEmbeddedAnnotations(DatastoreImpl.java:1545)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:1185)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:1167)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:1189)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:274)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:266)
    at repositories.UsersRepository.createUser(UsersRepository.java:65)
    at repositories.UsersRepository.main(UsersRepository.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In part, you're trying to serialize a `java.security.ProtectionDomain$Key` instance which neither Morphia nor the driver know how to do.  You'll need to write a `Converter` to manage that type.